# How can I recursively copy the directory contents and exclude the source directory itself?

Tags: ruby, copy, fileutils

Using FileUtils `cp_r` is usually how I copy directories, but I can't seem to exclude the base directory.  This is what I wanted to work, but it doesn't:

```
FileUtils.cp_r "#{source_path}\\**", target_path, :verbose => true
```

`source_path` has sub-directories I want to copy recursively.  I just don't want the actual `source_path` directory, just everything below it.

I tried using `Dir.glob` but could not get it right.

This is a Windows copy and I know I can use `xcopy` but want to know how to do it in Ruby.

Answer (score 13):

You want to use `source_path/.` instead of `source_path/**`, as describe in the last example of the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r)

```
➜  fileutils  ls
cp_files.rb dst         source
➜  fileutils  tree source 
source
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
└── deep
    └── d.txt

1 directory, 4 files
➜  fileutils  tree dst 
dst

0 directories, 0 files
➜  fileutils  cat cp_files.rb 
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp_r "source/.", 'dst', :verbose => true
➜  fileutils  ruby cp_files.rb 
cp -r source/. dst
➜  fileutils  tree dst
dst
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
└── deep
    └── d.txt

1 directory, 4 files
```

This is what cp_files.rb looks like:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp_r "source/.", 'dst', :verbose => true
```

Comment: If you have empty directories you wish to copy recursively, it is best practice to add a `.keep` file so they are not ignored from the recursive copy

Answer (score 5):

Please use the `FileUtils.copy_entry` utility. Provide the entire path for both source & destination. It will copy recursively from source to destination excluding the source parent directory. This method preserves file types, c.f. symlink, directory… (FIFO, device files and etc. are not supported yet)

Example usage:

```
src = "/path/to/source/dir"
dest = "/path/to/destination/dir"
preserve = false
dereference_root = false
remove_destination = false

FileUtils.copy_entry(src, dest, preserve, dereference_root, remove_destination)
```

Both of **src** and **dest** must be a path name. src must exist, dest must not exist.

If **preserve is true**, this method preserves owner, group, permissions and modified time. Optional use.

If **dereference_root is true**, this method dereference tree root. Optional use.

If **remove_destination is true**, this method removes each destination file before copy. Optional use.

For more information, [check out the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html).

Comment: This answer does not answer OP's question

Comment: @Srini I believe this does answer the OP's question